# I Created a branch in the wrong place in Tortoise SVN and I now want to shift it

Tags: tortoisesvn

In Tortoise SVN I was intending to create a branch into `/branches/NewBranch` but accidentally created it in `/trunk/NewBranch` without noticing and have since committed many changes.  How can I shift `/trunk/NewBranch` to `/branches/`?

I of course want to remove `/trunk/NewBranch` and have all the changes in the shifted branch `/branches/NewBranch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Tortoise SVN Gui.  In the SVN Repo browser, I right-clicked on `/trunk/NewBranch` and and used "Copy to..." to copy it to `/branches/NewBranch`.  I could then delete `/trunk/NewBranch`.  I can now happily switch between `/trunk` and `/branches/NewBranch`.  Everything seems as it should and hopefully, I've not overlooked something.

Answer (score 1):

You can move a branch to a different location in Tortoise SVN using below steps:

**Create a new branch at the correct location:** Right-click on your checkout directory and select TortoiseSVN -> Branch/tag.... In the "To URL" field, enter the correct URL for the new branch (i.e., `"/branches/NewBranch"`).

Be sure to enter a log message for this operation. Something like "Moving `/trunk/NewBranch` to `/branches/NewBranch"` would be appropriate.

**Switch to the new branch**: Right-click on your checkout directory and select TortoiseSVN -> Switch.... Enter the URL of the new branch (`"/branches/NewBranch"`).

This will update your working copy to point to the new branch.

**Commit any changes:** Any changes you made to the branch while it was in the wrong location should now be committed to the new branch.

**Delete the old branch**:Right-click on your checkout directory and select TortoiseSVN -> Repo-browser. Navigate to `"/trunk/NewBranch"`, right-click on it and select Delete.

You should add a log message for this operation too. Something like "Deleting old branch location `/trunk/NewBranch"` would be appropriate.

**Commit the deletion**: The deletion operation should have been added to your working copy. Right-click on your checkout directory and select SVN Commit... to commit this change to the repository.

**Update your working copy**: Lastly, right-click on your checkout directory and select SVN Update. This will update your working copy with the latest changes from the repository, including the deletion of the old branch.

PS: Remember to take a backup of any important changes before performing these operations, in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: did you get any part of this answer from an AI?